# How do you make mustard water?

Tags: sauce, condiments, mustard

I just found out the little bit of water that forms right above Dijon mustard tastes great when adding it on top of meat! Problem is that there is not much of that water in a Dijon mustard jar. Simply beating mustard with water doesn't quite do the trick.

I know it sounds disgusting (by itself) but when you add it to things it gives a great hint of Dijon raw mustard just cant create.

Answer (score 4):

Mustard is mostly vinegar, so instead of diluting mustard with water, try vinegar, or vinegar and water.

Comment: Also, use the same type of vinegar that's listed on the ingredients (usually white wine vinegar IME).

Comment: I suspect the OP's dilution attempt was not only not vinegary enough, but also not mustardy enough. This will only fix the former.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any kind of dilution will work. The water in your mustard jar is a lot more like mustard with the solids filtered out than mustard with extra liquid added. It's roughly in equilibrium with the mustard itself, so it's nice and full of all the mustard aromatics. If you add water, you reduce that concentration, and get something much less flavorful. If you remove the solids, well, that's what pretty much exactly what already happened in your jar.

So... if you want to make it out of pre-existing mustard, you could try to remove the solids, perhaps by squeezing in cheesecloth. Of course, that's kind of wasteful; you'll end up with a bunch of too-dry mustard.

If you want to feel a little less wasteful, you could try making your own mustard-infused vinegar. It's still going to be kind of the same thing - grinding mustard, infusing in vinegar (along with salt, sugar, etc), filtering out solids - but at least it'd be cheaper to start from whole mustard seed than from pre-made mustard. If you go this route, you could probably use any homemade mustard recipe as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could *try* diluting the mustard with water and/or vinegar with some soaking time and then filtering it through a coffee filter to remove the actual mustard.